# mp3player\MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.MyObjectBox;

Tags: java, android, objectbox

## MainApplication.java

#### I am relatively new to android and i'm trying to create a online music player app.I have used objectbox database for objects and i am getting the following error.i don't know how to fix it.Here are my following code

```
package lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.onesignal.OSNotification;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import io.objectbox.BoxStore;
import io.objectbox.annotation.Entity;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.helpers.ApiServices;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.helpers.RestClient;
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.MyObjectBox;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainApplication extends Application {
    private BoxStore mBoxStore;
    private static MainApplication sApp;
    private static GoogleAnalytics sAnalytics;
    private static Tracker sTracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sApp = MainApplication.this;
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenHandler())
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        sAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      
        mBoxStore = MyObjectBox.builder().androidContext(MainApplication.this).build();

        ApiServices apiService = RestClient.getApiService();
        final retrofit2.Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.getAds();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>()
```

## error

```
android_app\app\src\main\java\lrandomdev\com\online\mp3player\MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
import lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.models.MyObjectBox;
                                             ^
  symbol:   class MyObjectBox
  location: package lrandomdev.com.online.mp3player.model
```

Comment: Did you try to build it and how? "MyObjectBox" is the very first item in https://docs.objectbox.io/troubleshooting - please ensure the basic setup and if that is not working, please present additional details.